# in post increment Lvalue error

Tags: c++, c

```
int main()
{
    int[] x={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d",x);
    printf("%d",*x);
    printf("%d",++*x);
    printf("%d",*x++);   //Here Lvalue required erroe  is genrerated
}
```

Can someone please explain me what is meaning of this error and why it is generating here

Comment: Other errors aside, you're trying to increment an array. That makes no sense.

Comment: Congratulations. You now have your own official "this is why arrays and pointers are *not* the same* code sample to throw in the face of those that claim they are. Not that it matters, since your syntax is wrong anyway. `int[] x` should be `int x[]`. Might wanna fix that before winding up the pitching arm.

Comment: I am a java programmer.i Used to programm in c just few days ago.Si that i why fingers are still java oriented.Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to declare array in c/c++ is :

```
int x[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

The error is because you can not use ++ on array

Answer (score 0):

You can't increment an array.

`*x++` is the same as `*(x++)`. Maybe you wanted `(*x)++` instead?

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
printf("%d",*x++);
```

You are applying the `++` operator to the *array itself*, which is not possible. This gives you the lValue error.

Alternatively, in this one:

```
printf("%d",++*x);
```

You are applying the `++` operator to the *value pointed to by the array* (its first element), which of course works fine and just prints the value of next element.

Try

```
printf("%d",(*x)++);
```

Comment: its ok the increment in array makes no sense.But array is just a pointer variable. I mean if I print the value of x in my program(which is an array) it will print address of a[0].It mean it is pointer to a[0].So when I can use increment on a simple pointer variable then why I can not use increment operation on array pointer.

Comment: yes true Agree with you

Answer (score 0):

You can't increment an array. Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int x[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d",x);
    printf("%d",*x);
    printf("%d",++*x);
    int *y=x;
    printf("%d",*y++); //you can increment a pointer though
}
```

Answer (score -1):

its ok the increment in array makes no sense.But array is just a pointer variable. I mean if I print the value of x in my program(which is an array) it will print address of a[0].It mean it is pointer to a[0].So when I can use increment on a simple pointer variable then why I can not use increment operation on array pointer.

Comment: It is because array is not a pointer although it _behaves_ like a pointer.

Comment: Arrays are not pointer variables. However, they are automatically converted to a pointer to their first element when used in some expressions.